# How to I display results of phpcs in VIM?

Tags: php, vim, phpcodesniffer

I am presently trying to use PHP Codesniffer (PEAR) in vim for PHP Files.  I have found 2 sites that give code to add into the `$HOME/.vim/plugin/phpcs.vim` file.  I have added the code and I "think" it is working, but I cannot see the results, I only see one line at the very bottom of vim that says `(1 of 32)` but I cannot see any of the 32 errors.

Here is my .vimrc file

```
" Backup Options -> Some People may not want this... it generates extra files
set backup      " Enable Backups
set backupext=.bak  " Add .bak extention to modified files
set patchmode=.orig " Copy original file to with .orig extention Before saving.

" Set Tabs and spacing for PHP as recomended by PEAR and Zend
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set tabstop=4

" Set Auto-indent options
set cindent
set smartindent
set autoindent

" Show lines that exceed 80 characters
match ErrorMsg '\%80v.\+'

" Set Colors
set background=dark

" Show a status bar
set ruler
set laststatus=2

" Set Search options highlight, and wrap search
set hls is
set wrapscan

" File Type detection
filetype on
filetype plugin on

" Enable Spell Checking
set spell

" Enable Code Folding
set foldenable
set foldmethod=syntax

" PHP Specific options
let php_sql_query=1     " Highlight sql in php strings
let php_htmlInStrings=1 " Highlight HTML in php strings
let php_noShortTags=1   " Disable PHP Short Tags
let php_folding=1       " Enable Ability to FOLD html Code
```

I have tried 2 different versions of phpcs.vim, and I get the same results for both:

Version 1 (found at: [VIM an a PHP IDE](http://www.koch.ro/blog/index.php?/archives/63-VIM-an-a-PHP-IDE.html))

```
function! RunPhpcs()
    let l:filename=@%
    let l:phpcs_output=system('phpcs --report=csv --standard=YMC '.l:filename)
"    echo l:phpcs_output
    let l:phpcs_list=split(l:phpcs_output, "\n")
    unlet l:phpcs_list[0]
    cexpr l:phpcs_list
    cwindow
endfunction

set errorformat+=\"%f\"\\,%l\\,%c\\,%t%*[a-zA-Z]\\,\"%m\"
command! Phpcs execute RunPhpcs()
```

Version 2: (found at [Integrated PHP Codesniffer in VIM](http://www.koch.ro/blog/index.php?/archives/62-Integrate-PHP-CodeSniffer-in-VIM.html) )

```
function! RunPhpcs()
    let l:filename=@%
    let l:phpcs_output=system('phpcs --report=csv --standard=YMC '.l:filename)
    let l:phpcs_list=split(l:phpcs_output, "\n")
    unlet l:phpcs_list[0]
    cexpr l:phpcs_list
    cwindow
endfunction

set errorformat+="%f"\\,%l\\,%c\\,%t%*[a-zA-Z]\\,"%m"
command! Phpcs execute RunPhpcs()
```

Both of these produce identical results.

phpcs is installed on my system, and I am able to generate results outside of vim. Any help would be appreciated I am just learning more about vim...

Comment: I discovered my own answer. There were 2 problems. Problem 1: I did not have a cs name YML, I had to changed it to PHPCS, Problem 2: I did not know how to scroll through the list :cl -> lists all errors on the screen; :cnext -> shows the next error. So between the two of them it now works. Thanks for any reads hope it helps someone out.

Comment: Matt, please add the answer as answer and not as comment. Accept it then so that the answer is marked as "solved".

Answer (score 4):

Converting Matt's comment to an answer to get it from the unanswered questions list:

---

There were 2 problems.

1. I did not have a cs name YML, I had to changed it to PHPCS,
2. I did not know how to scroll through the list `:cl` -> lists all errors on the screen; `:cnext` -> shows the next error.

So between the two of them it now works. Thanks for any reads hope it helps someone out.